# Does Game Center score syncing work for sandbox accounts?

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard

I'm developing for iOS 6.0 and submitting scores to Game Center.  Everything works fine when I submit a score with an internet connection.

When I turn off my internet connection and submit a score that should update the leaderboard, the completion handler is invoked without any error.  When I turn the internet connection back on, I'm expecting GameKit to forward the score to Game Center and for the leaderboard to be updated.  But it doesn't update, not even after a long while (1+ hour).

The player is authenticated when the score is initially submitted and again when the internet connection is turned back on.

Am I missing something?  Does it work for sandbox accounts?  My score submission code is below:

```
- (void)submitScore:(int64_t)score category:(NSString*)category {

//1: Check if Game Center features are enabled

if (!_gcEnabled) {
    return;
}

//2: Create a GKScore object

GKScore* gkScore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];

//3: Set the score value

gkScore.value = score;

//4: Send the score to Game Center

[gkScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError* error) {

    [self setLastError:error];

    BOOL success = (error == nil);

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onScoresSubmitted:)]) {

        [_delegate onScoresSubmitted:success];
    }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the cached scores, i.e. the scores submitted to Game Center while there was no internet connection, are not sent automatically or immediately to Game Center when the internet connection is restored.  Instead, they are sent the next time a score is reported.

It seems that if I have cached scores for leaderboard category x, I have to submit a new score specific to that category.  Submitting a score for different category doesn't empty the cache for category x.

Comment: Of course, this might just be the behavior for games using the test environment with sandbox accounts.

Comment: On iTunes Connect, I set a score minimum > 0 for each leaderboard. When I detect that the network is reachable, I submit a GKScore object with  gkscore.value = 0 for each leaderboard.  Game Center rejects the score (as it should) and the local cache of GKScore objects for that leaderboard are cleared and resubmitted to Game Center.